# Can't feed imageView from a selected image in a tableView or collectionView into a detailView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm going from a collection or tableView and either one that I choose, it won't appear in the detail controller.

These are the errors I get:

[image]

Here is the code in the detailViewController:

```
var meme = SentMemeImageView.self

@IBOutlet weak var sentMemesBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var editBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var sentMemeView: UIImageView!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    displayMeme(meme)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func displayMeme(_ meme: SentMemeImageView) {

    sentMemeView.image = meme.memedImage

}

@IBAction func launchMemeEditorViewController(_ sender: Any) {
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}

//unwinding to the view before (the collectionView, or the tableView)

@IBAction func unwindVC(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, towardsViewController subsequentVC: UIViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

I need to call the `memedImage`, but from the struct `MemeImage` I was unable to call just the `memedImage` so I made another struct with just that, however I cannot call it to the detail view controller without those error's popping up.

```
struct MemeImage {
    let topText: String
    let bottomText: String
    let originalImage: UIImage
    let memedImage: UIImage
}


struct SentMemeImageView {
    let memedImage: UIImage
}
```

Thanks.

---

Update: AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?
        var memes = [MemeImage]()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            return true
   }
```

Comment: What is the prepare for segue look link in the table view that is passing the data to the detail view?

Comment: I don't have one. I did not put one because I did not think I needed one for presenting in storyboard instead of code.

Comment: How are you adding data to the meme Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TableViewController in the `prepareForSegue` you need to tell it what data to pass to the detailViewController.

```
var myData: [NSManagedObject] = []

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! detailViewController

        vc. meme = myData[selectedIndexPath.row]

}
```

Then in the detail viewDetailViewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var memeView: UIImageView!
var meme: NSManagedObject?  // You will use this for the index when pulling the image from how ever you are storing it. 

// The memeImage will need to be set from how ever you are storing the image.
self.memeView.image = UIIamge(named: meme)
```

Comment: When I put these in and added in my variable names, it caused more error's to come up.

Comment: Are you storing the data in CoreData? Are you retrieving it from some web database? I might help if you add a Update section to your question showing your code from the tableViewController has how you are getting the data for you tableView. Also when you say you are getting errors where are you getting them?

Comment: Hmm, I'm storing it in the AppDelegate (I was told to do so).  I will add update sections.

Comment: Update the question with a section of your AppDelegate that you are using to store the data.

Comment: Okay, I added the AppDelegate

Comment: I have a view that allows for whenever a photo is taken via camera, or chosen from the photo library, and after saving, it is put into the array of memes. Then, from there it is pushed to a tableViewController and a collectionViewController.

Comment: I changed the `self.memeView.image = memeImage` to `self.memeView.image = UIIamge(named: meme)' also you never said what errors you were getting.